# Show error, when selecting image in WordPress media uploader if params mismatch

Tags: plugin-development, media-modal

Good day !

My question is following:

I know how to show errors **while uploading** image from WordPress media uploader by using WordPress filter hook:

[image]

But **how to show same error box when user select an image** and hit "select" button. I want to add size check of selected image, before inserting. Any ideas how to do that ?

Thanks !

//Vladimir

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @cfx take a look at this solution http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142997/delete-an-attachment-in-the-wp-media-modal-window/157197#157197 and my plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/simplefavicon/9655701, i've done some hack based on CSS and JS